# How to map selected columns to Java Bean?

Tags: java, opencsv, supercsv

I have a CSV file with the following columns: id,name,description,price,date,pname,paddress

I have taken a nested Course class with id,name,description,price,date,Person data members and person class with pname,paddress
I want to map these columns to Person and Course object from a CSV file